# Gah! Trying to reset Core Data. Works every second time?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Alright, so my app delegate creates all the Core Data stuff, and I send to my first view controller.

My first view controller is a NSURLConnectionDelegate... in the connectionDidFinishLoading method,  I would like to erase the persistentStore and recreate it... and then parse/repopulate it from an XML file.

Here is my connectionDidFinishLoading code:

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

//I believe I should nil out the context...
managedObjectContext = nil;

//Erase the persistent store from coordinator and also file manager.
NSError *error = nil;
NSPersistentStore *store = [self.persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores lastObject];
NSURL *storeURL = store.URL;
[persistentStoreCoordinator removePersistentStore:store error:&error];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:storeURL error:&error];


//Make new persistent store and add to the coordinator  
if (![self.persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {
}
else {
    //Store is readied, now recreate the managedObjectContext
    id appDelegate = (id)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
managedObjectContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

   //Call the parser!
    [self parseXML];
}  
}
```

I know there's something wrong here... just can't figure out what.  It works every second time I Build/Run.   The error comes when I attempt to save the managedObjectContext in my parser methods

Can anyone provide the sample code on how I can fix this?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You're passing in `&error` for both the coordinator and the file manager - what errors are you getting back - `NSLog("%@", error);` after each call ;)

Comment: Not getting any errors on either of these... the error comes later in the [parseXML] method.   But I know it's related to this pasted code... if I take out all the persistent store removal bit and just [parseXML] it works

Comment: The error I'm getting is on "if (![managedObjectContext save:&error])"  and yea... only get the error every second time I run the app.  Error is "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"

Comment: How are you creating / retaining your managedObjectContext?

Comment: The managedObjectContext is created/passed from the app delegate using the standard core data method..  but yea, the managedObjectContext does seem to be released or something on the second Build/Run of the app...  The property is declared as " @property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;"

Comment: If you are removing the store, does that invalidate any managed objects associated with it - does your delegate need to recreate it's managed object context? Why are you storing your managed object context in the delegate but manipulating the coordinator in this class?

Comment: 1) not sure  2)I think you are supposed to nil managedObjectContext before making changes to persistentStore and then recreate.. but I've actually tried both ways and have same problem 3)I do pass the context from app delegate to view controller during init.. however, once I destroy it, I thought I had to go to app delegate to get it back

Comment: You're not niling the managed object context in the delegate, only the one in your current class ;) The one in the delegate might contain objects from / references to a store that doesn't exist anymore?

Comment: Gotcha... any chance you could supply some sample code for me in an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this working

(in my view controller)

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

id appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate resetCoreData];

self.managedObjectContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
[self parseXML];   
}
```

(in my app delegate)

```
- (void)resetCoreData;
{

NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"deleteme.sqlite"];

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];


    [fileManager removeItemAtURL:storeURL error:NULL];

    NSError* error = nil;

    if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:storeURL encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error]])
    {
        [fileManager removeItemAtURL:storeURL error:nil];
    }

self.managedObjectContext = nil;
self.persistentStoreCoordinator = nil;

}
```